# preg_match replace entire line

Tags: php, preg-match

I am new to PHP preg_match function. How to replace everthing with nothing before specific character using preg_match?

Sample:

```
text1
text2
text3
text3
# text 5
```

I want to get rid everything before the '#' sign. is that possible? here is my code bu not sure

```
$replace_match = '/^.*' . '#' . '.*$(?:\r\n|\n)?/m';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match all lines that do not start with `#` until you can match `#` at the start.

```
^(?:(?!#).*\R)+#
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!#).*\R` Negative lookahead, assert not `#` directly at the right. If that is the case, match the whole line followed by a newline
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single line
- `#` Match literally to make sure that the character is present

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ikEB1U/1)

In the replacement use a `#`

Example

```
$re = '/^(?:(?!#).*\R)+#/m';
$str = 'text1
text2
text3
text3
# text 5';

echo preg_replace($re, "#", $str);
```

Output

```
# text 5
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this one. I tried the `strstr()` and it works fine also not sure if that is the best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use preg_matches(),

if you want to remove all characters before some string, use [strpos()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp) function with some conditions and use [str_replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp) inside of the condition..

it is very simple and standard method to achieve this.